# bypass scheduler in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, api

Last night we during the disaster on k8s faced this issue that the scheduler does not respond to our apt request, so is there any way to bypass the k8s scheduler and direct way to deploy on the k8s cluster?
below is the logs that we have from it:

```
E0528 08:41:48.775507       1 runtime.go:78] Observed a panic: &errors.errorString{s:"feature \"PodOverhead\" is not registered in FeatureGate \"k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/util/feature/feature_gate.go:28\""} (feature "PodOverhead" is not registered in FeatureGate "k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/util/feature/feature_gate.go:28")
goroutine 1 [running]:
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/runtime.logPanic(0x153ddc0, 0xc00027a380)
    /go/src/sigs.k8s.io/descheduler/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/runtime/runtime.go:74 +0x95
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/runtime.HandleCrash(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/sigs.k8s.io/descheduler/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/runtime/runtime.go:48 +0x89
panic(0x153ddc0, 0xc00027a380)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:969 +0x1b9
k8s.io/component-base/featuregate.(*featureGate).Enabled(0xc0003a5140, 0x171d05b, 0xb, 0x0)
    /go/src/sigs.k8s.io/descheduler/vendor/k8s.io/component-base/featuregate/feature_gate.go:302 +0x237
sigs.k8s.io/descheduler/pkg/utils.PodRequestsAndLimits(0xc000210fa0, 0x157c, 0x6)
    /go/src/sigs.k8s.io/descheduler/pkg/utils/pod.go:142 +0x5dd
```

Answer (score 0):

found a way is to use k8s capabilities like node affinity and anti-affinity which you  can read more about it here: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2017/03/advanced-scheduling-in-kubernetes/